# 'Format String can be only "G", "g", "X", "x", "F", "f", "D" or "d".'

Tags: string, vb.net, insert, date-formatting

I have one query in vb.net.i am trying to insert date to SQL Database but when i click inset button then show me a error message above.Please if you can help me so i need yours advice.Thanks my code is below.
'In SQL database @DtoDOB Data type is Date.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DtpDOB", SqlDbType.Date.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy")).Value = DtpDOB.Value
```

Comment: `SqlDbType.Date` is an Enum, not a Date. Why are you calling `.ToString()` on it anyway? You seem to be trying to set the date format. That's not required and even if it was, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Please now tell me what is right code for this?

Comment: You just need to remove the `.ToString(..)` part as I mentioned above. Use `cmd.Parameters.Add("@DtpDOB", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DtpDOB.Value`.

Comment: i have try this parameter But now one more error show    'Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32.'

Comment: This continually marginally evolving problem now has an answer here: ['Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61108665/failed-to-convert-parameter-value-from-a-string-to-a-int32) - this question should be closed or deleted